# getting the namespace in xml file using querypath

Tags: php, xml, cakephp, querypath

I am using querypath for parsing my xml file. Its working fine , but now my requirement is that i need to get the name of the tag/namespace.
Ex:-

```
  <contact>
  <phone>738929238239</phone>
  <type>Mobile</type>
  </contact>
```

Now my requirement is that suppose i dont know wat are the namespaces present in the xml file. And i want to first get the namespaces like contact, phone,type from the above example. And than later on i need to get their corresponding element.

I can get the element names by mentioning the namespaces by below code..

```
<?php
require '../src/qp.php';
$xml ='test.xml';
echo "Printing individual Data<br />";
print qp($xml, 'phone')->text();
print qp($xml, 'type')->text();
echo "<br />Printing all the data<br />";
print qp($xml)->text();
?>
```

But how to display the tag names in querypath????